# Insert location coordinates into database after every 1 minute for that device

Tags: java, android, location, android-location, locationlistener

I am working on the application in which I need to store the `location` in the database after every `1 minute` for that particular `device/user`.

Suppose if user is moving while the application is open then his coordinates should keep on getting inserted into database after every `1 minute`. So for that I have my Web Services setup which can insert the data into the MySql Database. I have tested my WebService in the insertion part, it works fine.

But the problem that I am having is- I don't think so it is inserting into MySql database for that particular device/user after every `1 minute`. Can anyone tell me why it is not happening after every `1 minute`? And if there is any problem in the below code, can anyone help me out here by providing some example which will work as per my scenario above?

Any thoughts will be of great help.

```
private final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private final String sampleURL = ServerInfo.getServiceURL() + "/insert";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            60000, 
             0, 
            this.locationListener);

}
```

Below is the class that implements `LocationListener`.

```
private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
                }
     // Below code is used to insert into database
            String userId = id;
            String mLatitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            String mLongitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            String mProvider = location.getProvider();
            String mHasAltitude = Boolean.toString(location.hasAltitude());
            String mAltitude = Double.toString(location.getAltitude());
            String mHasSpeed = Boolean.toString(location.hasSpeed());
            String mSpeed = Float.toString(location.getSpeed());
            String mHasBearing = Boolean.toString(location.hasBearing());
            String mBearing = Float.toString(location.getBearing());
            String mHasAccuracy = Boolean.toString(location.hasAccuracy());
            String mAccuracy = Float.toString(location.getAccuracy());

            WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK,
                    getApplicationContext(), "Posting data...");

            wst.addNameValuePair("user_id", userId);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mlatitude", mLatitude);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mlogitude", mLongitude);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mprovider", mProvider);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mhasAltitude", mHasAltitude);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mAltitude", mAltitude);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mhasspeed", mHasSpeed);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mspeed", mSpeed);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mhasbearing", mHasBearing);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mbearing", mBearing);
            wst.addNameValuePair("mhasaccuracy", mHasAccuracy);
            wst.addNameValuePair("maccuracy", mAccuracy);

            // This will insert into database
            wst.execute(new String[] { sampleURL });


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

**NOTE:-**  It is inserting into Database but it's not inserting at exactly or approximately in the time interval I need which is of `1 minute`

Comment: What evidence do you have that it isn't inserting the data into your database? Or is the problem that it doesn't happen at exactly the time interval you want?

Comment: i think you have to save all data of location in local sqlite database & at some interval you have to send data to mysql this will help when network is not available.

Comment: @Code-Guru, It is inserting into Database but it doesn't happen at exactly or approximately the time interval I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be caused by several issues which are not directly under your control as a programmer. Some that come to mind are

1. The network may not be available and therefore no positioning data can be sent to your app.
2. An ill-behaved app is taking up CPU time and the OS doesn't interrupt it within your desired time interval.

In general, getting exact timing on a device designed for multi-tasking is nearly impossible. There can also be issues with getting data at "approximate" time intervals depending on what margin of error you can accept.

Comment: Thanks for the Information Code-Guru. So as per my scenario that I mentioned above, it should work fine with this `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            60000, 
             0, 
            this.locationListener);`. Right? If there is any problem, then it can be mostly with the issues you mentioned above?

Comment: @TechGeeky I'm not familiar with using location services, so I can't say for sure. It's quite possible that there is a problem with your code. I'm trying to point out that there are other reasons that you are seeing this problem. I'm uncertain how to determine which is the real reason.